# How do I hide previous slide in a simple jQuery slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hide, slideshow

I'm creating an online portfolio for my girlfriend and for that a simple slideshow of images with fade transitions. I want to be able to "hide" the previous "last-active" slide, when a new "active" one is shown.

I've modified the slideshow provided here (http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow), so instead of an automatic cycle, it is controlled by 'prev / next' buttons. That all works great.
Contrary to the above example, I need to have different sized images in the slideshow.

Problem: The way the slideshow works, like a stack of images, I'm seeing the previous image behind the current "active" one. E.g. when switching between a vertical (portrait) image and a horizontal (landscape) image, i can see the landscape one behind the portrait one.

I've tried the jQuery .hide() method within the $nextSlide() function, but not sure if that's the right way to do it. I'm a complete javascript and jQuery novice.

HTML:

```html
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="active">
        <img src="horizontal.jpg">
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="vertical.jpg">
    </div>

</div>

<div id="controls">
<span class="control-prev">prev</span> / <span class="control-next">next</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:400px;
}

#slideshow DIV {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
}

#slideshow DIV.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow DIV.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

#slideshow DIV IMG {
    height: 350px;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function nextSlide() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active'); 
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV:last'); 


    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next() 
        : $('#slideshow DIV:first');


    $active.addClass('last-active');
    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}
$(".control-next").click(function(){
    nextSlide();
    });

´´´

The goal is to have a slideshow that doesn't show the images like a stack. I bet the solution is very simple, but I can't work it out.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the active and last-active classes from your div... reset their opacity back to 0.0 so next time it will animate (fade in) again:

```
function nextSlide() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active'); 
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV:last'); 


    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next() 
        : $('#slideshow DIV:first');


    $active.addClass('last-active');
    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300, function() {
            $active.css({opacity: 0.0})
                   .removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}
```

If you also want it to fade-out, rather than just going to opacity 0... use the following:

```
$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
            .addClass('active')
            .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300, function() {
                $active.css({opacity: 1.0})
                       .animate({opacity: 0.0}, 300, function(){
                          $active.removeClass('active last-active')
                       });
            });
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your quick reply on my question.

I just tried adapting the above, and it actually hides the slide behind the current one, which was just what I was looking for. There is just the thing, that the script seems to be executed line by line, from top to bottom. That means that the last-active slide is first hidden after the fade animation is finished.

But that also means that when I remove the fade animation, the slide is hidden immediately! I'm definitely on the right path - now I just need to find a way to keep the fade animation.

Comment: Basically you are looking for fade out. i have updated the code.

Comment: Thanks! I also figured out adding the fade-out, but the problem is still that the fade-in animation of the new slide has to finish playing before the next line of code is executed. Meaning that when I click 'next', the previous slide is shown behind the new one in 0.3 seconds while the fade-in animation is playing, and first after that, the previous slide will fade out or immediately hide. I guess the trick is to either have it all executed at the same time or by filling out the space surrounding an image with white, so that the image behind it cannot be seen. I appreciate your help!

Comment: the order is right there in the code. you can fade out current slide first and fade in next slide second. it is all in the order you specify in your code.